# Client Crash Reports on Production Apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

I have an app in the appstore and I would like to be aware about client crashes. is there any way through coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few things you can look at:

[PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) from Landon Fuller - a crash reporting library you can bundle in your app.

[MacDevCrashReporter](http://macdevcrashreports.com/) looks like a combination of a PLCrashReporter-based tool on the phone and a web service for viewing information about submitted crash reports. Haven't used it, but the web service is PHP-based - if it doesn't offer any sort of email notifications, you can probably edit the code to send you email notifications (or some other sort of notification system).

Of course, there's also the Crash Reporter page in iTunes Connect - log in, select the application you want to manage, select View Details of the current version, and select the Crash Reports link. I've sometimes found that I need to click the Reload Now link to get reports to appear.

Comment: Based on your answer I've found this https://github.com/TheRealKerni/CrashReporterDemo that uses PLCrashReporter. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Flurry SDK.  Its free, easy to use and provides tons of stats about your app and its usage.  [www.flurry.com](http://www.flurry.com)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw that link in another post but Jablair answer is what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/)! an overall client side and server side solution for crash logs.
It is also based on PLCrashReporter.